# Can we use User class from spring security directly with CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Security to set up a POC.
I want to have authentication with basic content that why I used directly  [User class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) from Spring Security.
I'm also using apache derby as an embedded database. I want to use [CrudRepository class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) from Spring data to have a UserRepository (database where I can store my Users).
I get an error while running my project saying that It's not a managed type.
Only Solution I got is to extends this class.
Does Someone have a better solution ?

Thanks

Edit : Please just ask question if my question is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `@Entity` as type for a `Repository`.

`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` is not an `@Entity`, it's just an mutable implementation of UserDetails.

You can implement `UserDetails` for your own `@Entity`.

Comment: That confirms what I thought !
Seems weird to me that they haven't thought about making it an Entity.

Comment: It's not that much weird. JPA and Spring Security are just different standards for different requirements.